# Unification of DVCS commands

Tags: git, mercurial, dvcs

When working on multiple (open source) projects, multiple version controll systems start to be problematic. While they share common operations, I often make mistakes by typing *hg add* instead *git add*.

I remember seeing project some time ago that made access to different source control software in uniform way by providing basic commands *commit/ci* *add* etc. in shell. Depending on repository it would in turn call *hg add* or *git add* etc.

I've seen Amp: http://amp.carboni.ca/ (which seems to be down ATM) any other scripts like that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think unifications of two (in this case *completely* different) version control systems is not a sensible thing to attempt. While there are certain commonalities, **the differences far outweigh the commonalities.** More specifically, while you could map certain commands from one system to a similar command in another system, there will still be **semantic differences because Mercurial and Git have completely different internal models.** Just consider how branching is represented or git's staging area.

Instead of trying to unify both systems at the "user" level, I think it is much more desirable to stick with one version control system and, if required, backport your changes/history to another system using a bridge (similar to git-svn).

Typing `hg add` vs. `git add` is not something that can get really dangerous if your current directory is not a repository managed in both systems, so you'll get a meaningful error message.

Comment: I completely agree with you about the significant differences between various VCSes. Unfortunately, sticking with one isn't always possible; in particular, I don't believe there's a good way to use git to work on a mercurial repo (i.e. there's hg-git but not git-hg).

Comment: Fact is, most common operations in both hg, and git are almost identical, and very common, so I'd much prefer simply typing _add file_ and for it to work in both hg and git directory, and do nothing (or print warnign message) in directories not under version controll.

Comment: @Marcin Raczkowski `git add` and `hg add` aren't even _close_ to being the same.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of.
The two repos for amp ([on GitHub](http://github.com/michaeledgar/amp), and [on bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org/carbonica/amp/src)) are not exactly bursting right now.
And the [comments about the project](http://www.rubyinside.com/amp-ruby-source-control-revolution-2857.html) were not all enthusiastic.

So right now, common aliases/commands (able to recognized their context - hg or git repo - and generate the right command) are your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

I think this was one of the goals of [anyvcs](http://www.stackfoundry.com/other/anyvcs/), but I don't know how far along it is.

Answer (score 0):

There are also [Push Me Pull You](http://pmpu.sharesource.org/) and [Qct](http://qct.sourceforge.net/) project, both are multi-DVCS GUIs.

I have not checked their status, though.