# Building a git bridge

Tags: git, version-control, integration

I'm looking for a generic git bridge (like git-svn, git-p4, git-tfs) template that could be used to integrate any source control management system.

If there is no such template, at least some instructions on how to integrate the basic operations on the git side (for the other SCM I'm aware that I need to use some external tools, but It would be great to have a generic template where to plug in the SCM commands and the template to do the rest of the work - for example to create the commit on git).

There is a project called [git-remote-helpers](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote-helpers.html) but I'm not sure it's exactly what I need (basically it adds transport protocol support for git).

[added:]
This is how I see the things, for the following commands (the basic set):

1. git scm init:

   - create the repository settings (if the case setup an internal working folder, a remote workspace - example: tfs, accurev) and create a remote scm/origin
2. git scm fetch:

```
foreach changeset in scm.changesets
    scm.retreive changeset
    git.createcommit (changeset.data)
end
```

1. git scm clone = init + fetch
2. git scm push:

```
check_remote_scm // do we need to fetch and/or rebase?
build commit_package(git.branch.commits)
foreach commit_data in commit_package
    scm_commit_meta = scm.push commit
    git.updatecommit commit_data.git_data scm_commit_meta
end
```

There are other commands that could be added to the list - these are just the basic commands, that would allow someone to work with any SCM.

Answer (score 3):

When talking about "[Unification of DVCS commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647962/unification-of-dvcs-commands)", there are [some reservations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3648068/6309) about such a project.

The [old one "amp" (2009-2010)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4756975/6309) isn't active anymore.
[mr is supposed to provide the kind of universal command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4759638/6309), integrating the git ones.

Comment: actually what I'm looking is to extend git to support some other SCM (an equivalent for git-svn, git-p4, etc)

Comment: @BogdanMaxim then you can extend https://github.com/visionmedia/git-extras/ : git-extras: currently oriented for git, but with room for improvement, including other VCS.